# Foursquare API, return only selected fields

Tags: api, foursquare

We practically need just few things (name, id, location) from the whole Foursquare venue detail request

Is there a way how to restrict the Foursquare response only to some / given fields?

Facebook allows adding ?fields=name,location... to a request, we need smth. like this with Foursquare

Comment: I would need the same, Did you find any solution to do that??

Comment: I talked to people from FSQ , it is not possible :( at least it was not a year ago

Comment: many thanks. I will try to ask them again then :-P

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any way to do this with the API. You should just use the fields you need from the response you get from Foursquare!

Comment: thats just a waste of resources on both sides :/